# On dissecting a triangle into another triangle

Tags: discrete-geometry, triangles, scissors-congruence

It is easy to see that an equilateral triangle can be cut into 2 identical 30-60-90 degrees right triangles which can then be patched together to form a 30-30-120 degrees triangle. So, via 2 intermediate pieces, we can dissect an equilateral triangle into the 30-30-120 triangle of the same area.

**Question:** Find two equal area, non-congruent triangles T1 and T2 such that T1 can be cut into 3 (and not less than 3) pieces which can be reassembled into T2. Not sure if such a T1-T2 pair exists.

One can readily generalize and ask for equal area {T1-T2} pairs which can be dissected into each other via n (and not less than n) intermediate pieces (n cannot be arbitrarily large, from the Wallace-Bolyai-Gerwein theorem).

**Further question:** What can one say about equal area pairs of triangles which are the worst for mutual dissection - ie for which the number of intermediate pieces is the highest possible? 
**Guess:** a triangle pair with **equal area and equal perimeter** is bad for mutual dissection.

**Further Note - Going to Pairs of Quadrilaterals:** the problem is trivial for rectangles - indeed, for any rectangle R and any n, there is a different rectangle with same area as R and n times as long which can be got by cutting R into n equal, length-parallel strips and attaching them end to end. For general quadrilaterals, things seem less trivial. For any cyclic quad Q (each pair of opposite vertices of Q add to 180 degrees), it appears that we can cut Q into 2 pieces and patch these to get another quad Q' different from Q. But for non-cyclic Q's, one is not sure of finding such a Q' even for n =2. For general n, things appear harder.

Comment: If the problem is solvable for rectangles for arbitrary n, then it should be solvable for right triangles for arbitrary n. Gerhard "Just Use Half A Rectangle" Paseman, 2020.01.20.

Comment: Speaking of rectangles, here is a quick solution to the question. From a rectangle corner, draw lines to the midpoints or the sides not adjacent to a corner. This gives a three piece dissection which can form two non congruent triangles.  I suspect there is a proof that this cannot be replaced by a two piece dissection. Gerhard "Ready Rectangles To The Rescue!" Paseman, 2020.01.20.

Comment: Just checked your construction. Yes, it does yield two non-congruent right triangles which can be dissected into each other via *3* intermediate pieces. And no 2-piece dissection seems to work! But I don't readily see how it generalizes to n greater than 3.

Comment: The three piece construction doesn't; the 1 by mn to m by n rectangle extends to triangles, although it is not clear that exactly n pieces are needed. Gerhard "Perhaps Something Close To N" Paseman, 2020.01.20.