# Cutting off odd numbers of equal area triangles from a unit square

Tags: nt.number-theory, discrete-geometry, triangles

Two earlier related posts:

1. [Cutting the unit square into pieces with rational length sides](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351838/cutting-the-unit-square-into-pieces-with-rational-length-sides)
2. [On a possible variant of Monsky's theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394721/on-a-possible-variant-of-monskys-theorem)

**Question:** for odd n, how does one cut the unit square into n equal area triangles of maximum possible area - thereby minimizing the portion of the square left over? Does this question have to be answered for each n separately?

Define f(n) as the fraction of the area of the unit square that gets left out by the optimal way of cutting n equal area triangles from it. Then, how does f(n) behave as n increases?

**Further question:** Does requiring that the areas of the triangles cut be rational have any interesting implications?

Comment: The rational requirement certainly doesn't affect $f(n)$, because for a given triangle one can choose a slightly smaller triangle with rational coordinates whose area is arbitrarily close to the starting area, so a solution which leaves some area $A$ behind can easily be converted into a rational-coordinate solution which leaves $A+\epsilon$ behind for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! The question may be nontrivially affected if say, we insist all sides of all triangles to be rational. But that would be another question.