# Which polygons allow partition into rational triangles?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, diophantine-geometry

A triangle with all side lengths rational is said to be a rational triangle. It is known - for example, [Cutting the unit square into pieces with rational length sides](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351838/cutting-the-unit-square-into-pieces-with-rational-length-sides) - that the unit square allows partition into triangles all of which are rational. It follows from the above-linked discussion that any rectangle with length and width rational (diagonal whatever) can be cut into rational rectangles by a recursive application of the unit square method (thanks to Peter Taylor for clarifying this point I had overlooked in an earlier post).

**Question:** for a general polygon P to be divisible into some finite number of rational triangles, it is obviously necessary that all sides of P are rational in length. What could one say about sufficiency conditions? As a special case, how could one characterize a quadrilateral that can be cut into some finite number of rational triangles?

Comment: There are only countably many angles that occur in rational triangles.  So only countably many polygons can be cut into finitely many rational triangles.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't the set of all polygons with all edges of rational length (polygons satisfying just the necessary condition mentioned in question) already countable?

Comment: No. The set of side length sequences is countable, but varying the angles between them may give an uncountable set for a single side length sequence. E.g. there's an uncountable set of unit rhombi.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the freedom - and uncountability - in angles. So, could one say that (say) in addition to all sides being rational, the cosines of all angles of P being rational would be a better (stronger) necessary condition?

Comment: Yes, that would be a necessary condition.